# Using variables in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Essentially what I'm trying to do is replace a few values in the JSON string with some variables that I have. Here's a snapshot of my code:

```
listproxies = ['proxy1', 'proxy2', 'proxy3']

PROXY = random.choice(listproxies)

proxy_host = PROXY[:-28]
proxy_port = '12345'
proxy_username = PROXY[25:-9]
proxy_password = 'password'

print("USING PROXY: "+proxy_host+":"+proxy_port+":"+proxy_username+":"+proxy_password)

manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: """+proxy_host+""",
            port: parseInt("""+proxy_port+""")
          },
          bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: """+proxy_username+""",
            password: """+proxy_password+"""
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
"""
```

As you can see, in `background_js` I'm trying to call the variables `proxy_host` and `proxy_port`, and then `proxy_username` & `proxy_password` further down, which doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: use `.format()`

Comment: How is it not working? Except for a missing `import random` your posted code runs without an error. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

JSON format allows only double quotes: `""`
Using single quotes `''` or `""" """` is not allowed.

Comment: Yep and I understand that however if I only used double quotes ("") the variable doesn't get registered as a variable, and is simply just added to the JSON string...

Comment: @AngusTimoney You can use string formatting for that. "host: {}".fromat(proxy_host). Curly parentheses will get replaced by proxy_host variable. You can have as many "{}" as you want, you just have to mach their number with a number of arguments passed to format.

Comment: I just tried that but It's throwing me the KeyError: '\n            mode' error, see my updated JSON here: https://pastebin.com/eKYpHkYA

Answer (score -1):

Use the builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library, and deal with this stuff as if it was a dictionary instead.

```
>> import json
>> manifest_as_json = json.loads(manifest_json)
>> manifest_as_json['version'] = 1.2.3
>>
>> import pprint
>> pprint.pprint(manifest_as_json)
{
    "version": "1.2.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
```

Additionally, if you'd like to, you could use the fstrings in Python and just embed variables into the string:

```
>> pretty_proxy_host = f"This is my {proxy_host}"
>> print(pretty_proxy_host)
This is my proxy1
```